# Drawing multiple triangles with different colors on OpenGL ES 2.0

Tags: java, android, opengl-es, sdk, geometry

I'm trying to figure how to this on OpenGL for SDK using OpenGL ES 2.0 in Java. I want to draw multiple triangles (most like arbitrary) with different colors. I currently have a `Triangle` class that can draw a triangle with a color, coordinates passed in as a `FloatBuffer` and color passed in as an array (pretty much following [this](http://developer.android.com/training/graphics/opengl/shapes.html) example since I'm just a beginner to OpenGL).

I tried adding more points to the coordinate array before putting it in the `FloatBuffer`, but unfortunately that just draws the triangles as one single polygon, and I can't change the color for each individual triangle.

May I get some help on this on how to best start this? I was thinking about creating each class for each triangle, but I don't know if that will be efficient when it comes to drawing a bunch of triangles with different colors. If there is any other simple way, I would really like to hear.

Comment: What kind of aim do you have? The solutions can be very different, when you compare static objects or dynamic "particle" systems.

Comment: I have a slider on my view, and when the user changes the slider, I would change my coordinate and color buffers, kind of like redrawing the triangles with different colors again. This would be done as many times as the user wishes, so I'm looking for something efficient to redraw the triangles.

Comment: The best thing is, to google this: "VBO OpenGL GL_DYNAMIC_DRAW", I think this topic could be yours ;)